# Batch File Not working correctly at startup

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

So I wrote a batch file to open and close an application after 5 seconds (In Windows 7). Here is the code:

```
 if "%1" == "" start "" /min "%~dpnx0" MY_FLAG && exit
 @echo off
 cd "C:\Users\owner\Downloads\"
 Start "" /b ThrottleStop.exe 
 timeout /T 5 /nobreak >nul
 taskkill /IM ThrottleStop.exe /F
 exit
```

I will now give an instance of when in works correctly and when it does not:

Test 1: Run batch file by clicking on it.
Result: Command prompt Opens, code runs, the Application open and closes after 5 seconds. This test is a success.

Test 2: Place a shortcut to the same Batch file in the startup folder to execute upon each log in.
Result: When logged in the command prompt opens and appears to start running. However application NEVER opens, the batch file simply exits. This test is a failure.

Test 3: Set Task Scheduler to execute Batch file every login. When logged in the command prompt opens and appears to start running. However application NEVER opens, the batch file simply exits. This test is a failure.

Following Test 2 and 3 I tried running it manually again and it executes correctly. So the issue is only auto running it at startup. Is it possible that it needs a delay in it due to certain processes not booting up yet (on Windows side)?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between "works fine" and "not working correctly"? You should take the [tour] and read [Ask]. From your description, it seems to be doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Please re-read the post. I clearly state the problem here:  If I put a shortcut in the startup folder or run it using Task Scheduler I get the following message in the CMD prompt: "SUCCESS: The process "ThrottleStop.exe"     with PID 2216 has been terminated."                                                            Also the problem is stated clearly in the header "Batch File Not working correctly at startup" so I am not sure what you are confused by.

Comment: Yes I read that. It is quite clear that ThrottleStop.exe has been terminated, and that seems to be exactly what your script does, start and then kill the process.  Take the [tour], read [Ask]. [Edit] your post to include both the expected and witnessed outputs. Explain why successfully killing ThrottleStop.exe is not the behavior you expected.

Comment: @David, none of us knows what you expect to happen that is not happening. Please explain further.

Comment: I have edited my question to be as clear as I possibly can.

Answer (score 0):

If you want ThrottleStop to exit 5 seconds after it starts, add this line to the ThrottleStop.INI configuration file.

ExitTime=5

If you want to know how to properly use the Task Scheduler, follow the ThrottleStop Task Scheduler Guide exactly.  There are options in the Task Scheduler that need to be disabled.

http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/the-throttlestop-guide.531329/#post-6865107

Comment: Yes I read this forum before, though the issue was that I did not see a good way to immediately kill the app. This is a good solution too, though i Wish I understood why the batch doesnt work correctly when autostarted at login.